# In python, how can I find "# The Scenes" from "Behind # The Scenes" with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I want to get the string `## The Scenes` from `Behind ## The Scenes` with regex.

This is the regex I have made.

```
pattern = re.compile("#+\s\w+")
```

When I run the script, I get `d ## The Scenes` string.

How can I?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://ideone.com/ZWczaJ.

Comment: I also get "## The"

Comment: You can't be getting this as `"\s\w+"` stands for "_one_ space, one or more word characters", so you should get `"## The"`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, your regex pattern isn't matching "d ## The Scenes", it's matching "## The". If you want "## The Scenes", this pattern adds an extra space and word to yours and should work:

"#+\s\w+\s\w+"

Comment: It's not a good pattern, because it won't work for strings like "Behind ## The Scenes" or "Behind ## The Scenes And More Words".

Comment: Why doesn't it work for "Behind ## The Scenes"? I designed it to **not** match all of "Behind ## The Scenes And More Words" because it's not clear that OP wants that behavior.

Comment: Your pattern seems like hardcode, and my pattern is more flexible.

Comment: And I didn't say that it doesn't work for "Behind ## The Scenes". ;)

Answer (score 0):

How did you get "## The Scenes"? I don't know. Having used your pattern, I got "## The".

But the code like this:

```
pattern = re.compile("#+[\s\w]+")
```

works perfectly.

I think, it is what you need.

Comment: This will grab all of the words following "##", which might not be what OP wants.

Comment: But falcon.guru didn't specify, what the code have to return for other strings.